# Trouble with printf conversion long long

Tags: c, printf, long-integer

I've been working on a project euler problem, which by their very nature coerce you to use data types with big storage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define num 600851475143

int main()
{
long long i, j, count=0, number=num, k;
for(i=2;number!=1;i++)
{
    count=0;
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if((i%j)==0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(k=0;k<100000000;k++)
    {}
    if(count==2)
    {
        printf("                      %d\n", i);
        if(number%i==0)
        {
            number/=i;
            printf("      %d\n", number);
            printf("%d\n", i);
            i=2;
        }
    }
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run the program, there is nothing printed for number. I have tried various printf conversions %ll, %l, I have changed data types. I am using GNU GCC compiler. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You should (re)read [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), I guess.

`%ll` didn't work since `ll` is not a complete specifier, it's just a modifier for the actual conversion specifier, which should follow.

Try `%lld`.

Comment: i believe there is a problem in the condition if(number%i==0), since it does not print anything even if i want to printf("Hello") inside its block. Is it possible that there are size restrictions for data inside if?

Comment: @user1794004 May be your terminal, it prints here (and is on the whole surprisingly unslow).

Answer (score 2):

The correct format for `printf` is `%lld`. Moreover you should use a prefix for your constant `num`, because this integer constant is too large to be hold in `long` type.

```
#define num 600851475143LL
```

Perhaps should you avoid lower-case macro's identifiers?