# cannot go above 2147483647 (2 ^ 31) limit

Tags: visual-c++

Just to start with I am new to programming, and do not know a lot about C++ yet.

I'm using the "long long" data type, and do have a 64 bit processor, however when doing long long * long long i end up with a negative (or signed) number, with output of -2.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    unsigned long long number = 2147483647;
    unsigned long long number2 = 2;
    printf("%d \n", number * number2);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest taking a look at the table [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)?  There's a mismatch between the `printf` specifier and the actual type you're trying to display.

Comment: use `"%lld"` to print a `long long` and `"%llu"` for `unsigned long long`, check [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: @JustinTime Thankyou, that helped, i changed %d to %u. It has a limit of 2^32 now, however considering it is long long data type, shouldn't the limit be 2^64

Comment: `%d` and `%u` by themselves simply match `signed int` and `unsigned int`, respectively; this is because `int` is considered the "default" integral type.  Just like the type keywords themselves, they need special qualifiers if you desire an integral type other than the "default" one.  As @BeyelerStudios mentioned, `%lld` matches `signed long long int` (`long long`), and `%llu` matches `unsigned long long int` (`unsigned long long`), for example.  Similarly, `%ld` matches `signed long int` (`long`), and `%hu` matches `unsigned short int` (`unsigned short`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with printf conversion long long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194067/trouble-with-printf-conversion-long-long)